# Select Oldest Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I want to select the Oldest Dates values on a Date Column.

**Example:** 
I want to get 30% of the Oldest Dates. If I have 10 Registers, I want to get the bottom/oldest 3.

**Example 2:**

If:
John has been working since 2005
Gina has been working since 2003
Mark has been working since 2000
Lou has been working since 2015

I want to get the Mark and Gina, because they've been working more time in the company.

Comment: not sure what you mean, please post some sample data and expected result. Basically, you can use TOP and just change the `ORDER BY` from `DESC` to `ASC` or the other way to get the bottom

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output to your question.

Comment: I think this way is more "understandable".

Comment: `lowest` is earliest or latest date ?

Comment: Oldest dates in the Table.

Comment: Please have a look at the answer that i posted. It will help you get Mark & Gina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you still use `SELECT TOP` statement, just change the `ORDER BY` with `ASC` or `DESC` to return the result in ascending or descending order

Here are some sample query to illustrate

```
-- Create a Sample Table
declare @sample table
(
    date_col    date
)

-- Insert some sample dates
insert into @sample select getdate()
insert into @sample select getdate() - 1
insert into @sample select getdate() - 2
insert into @sample select getdate() - 3
insert into @sample select getdate() - 4
insert into @sample select getdate() - 5

-- Get TOP 3 rows order by date in ascending (oldest to latest)
select  top 3 *
from    @sample
order by date_col

-- Get TOP 3 rows order by date in descending (latest to oldest)
select  top 3 *
from    @sample
order by date_col desc

-- Get TOP 30 percent, total 6 rows so 30% is 2 rows in ascending order
select  top (30) percent *
from    @sample
order by date_col

-- in descending order
select  top (30) percent *
from    @sample
order by date_col desc
```

Comment: Simple as that. Sometimes little things stop you for too much time haha. Thank you! Worked perfectly.

This one worked for me:
select  top (30) percent *
from    @sample
order by date_col